# How to create stored procedure with multiple inputs that have default values?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I attempting to create a stored procedure that takes two values, a start, and end row value. The start on default should be a count on rows returned from a select view and the end is 60 values from the start. The problem I am running into is declaring both values with parameters if none was passed and using those values further down.

I have tried using declare and no luck.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getRecords] 
    (@StartLoc INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[dashboardview]),
     @EndLoc INT = @StartLoc - 60)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT         
        o.ID, o.Name, o.DateRan, s.Name AS Job, o.Start, o.[End],
        o.Status, o.Logs 
    FROM            
        dbo.output AS o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        dbo.jobs AS j ON o.Job = j.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        dbo.scripts AS s ON  j.Script = s.ID 
    WHERE 
        (o.DateRan < GETDATE()) 
        AND (ROW_NUMBER() >= @StartLoc And ROW_NUMBER()<= @EndLoc)
    ORDER BY 
        o.ID
END
```

My aim is to return the number of records between the specified range.

Comment: You have several things going on here that aren't quite right. You can't use ROW_NUMBER without at least an order by. But you can't use it in the where clause like that either. Also, logically this is flawed because how could ROW_NUMBER return a value greater than the count of rows?

Comment: @SeanLange I will revise how to set the range

Answer (score 2):

Set the Default values to NULL, and then do a check to set the values if they are NULL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getRecords] 
  @StartLoc INT = NULL,
  @EndLoc INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF @StartLoc IS NULL 
    SET @StartLoc = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[dashboardview]);

  IF @EndLoc IS NULL
    SET @EndLoc = @StartLoc - 60;

  ...
```

Comment: This suffers the same logical problems that the OP posted. We now have StartLoc being a higher number than EndLoc. But it **does** accurately fix the problem stated by the OP. So still worth a +1 from me. ;)

Comment: The OP is referencing `ROW_NUMBER` in the `WHERE` (and without an `OVER` and `ORDER BY` clause); they can't actually do that.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* this might be what the OP is after... A little bit difficult to tell, if I'm honest:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getRecords] @StartLoc INT = NULL,@EndLoc INT = NULL
AS BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     IF @StartLoc IS NULL BEGIN
          SET @StartLoc = 0;
     END ELSE BEGIN
          SET @StartLoc = @StartLoc - 1;
     END;

     IF @Endloc IS NULL BEGIN
          SELECT @EndLoc = COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[dashboardview];
     END ELSE BEGIN
          SET @EndLoc = @Endloc - @StartLoc
     END;

     SELECT o.ID,
            o.Name,
            o.DateRan,
            s.Name AS Job,
            o.Start,
            o.[End],
            o.Status,
            o.Logs 
     FROM  dbo.output AS o 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.jobs AS j ON o.Job = j.ID
               LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.scripts AS s ON j.Script = s.ID 
     WHERE (o.DateRan < GETDATE()) 

     ORDER BY o.ID
     OFFSET @StartLoc ROW FETCH NEXT @EndLoc ROWS ONLY;
END
GO
```

Ideally the logic for `@EndLoc` should be number of rows instead of the end location, as that means that you don't need to change the value (and `@startLoc` should be a 0 start, not a 1 start).

Comment: Amazing solution, however, I am trying to modify now because my start will be the last record as I am counting in descending order so my start will be the bottom and end 60 - that.

Comment: Then simply change the `ORDER BY` to descending, @robdigm ... That information was impossible to infer from your query I'm afraid, as your `ROW_NUMBER` function was missing both an `OVER` and `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: When I execute, now i get this 'Msg 10744, Level 15, State 1, Procedure dbo.getRecords, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 2]
The number of rows provided for a FETCH clause must be greater then zero.'

Comment: What is the `EXEC` statement, @robdigm? I **assumed** that `@EndLoc` would be greater than `@StartLoc`, because you know, that makes sense.

Comment: EXEC [dbo].[getRecords]

Comment: I'd put `@Rows` in stead of `@endLoc` in error @robdigm, but I would has expected a different error because of that. There *are* rows in the table `[dbo].[dashboardview]` right..? Otherwise that SQL will error, yes.

Comment: Oh I made those changes. Yeah [dbo].[dashboardview] is a view created. I ran the same SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[dashboardview] on the view and got the number while testing prior to posting the question.

Comment: I got it to work. Not sure what I alterd but it works now!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @robdigm. Please do make it as the soluy if it solved the problem so that future readers know it was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Just noticed one minor issue I overlooked. the rows are not coming across increments of 60